# In Z24 list all generators for the subgroup of order 8. Let G 5 a and let |a| 5 24. List all generators for the subgroup of order 8.

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Z24 list all generators for the subgroup of order 8. Let G 5 a
and let |a| 5 24. List all generators for the subgroup of order 8.

Comment: When you say "5", do you mean "="? And more generally, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when formatting math on this site.

Comment: There's a well-known formula for the order of an element $x$ in the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_n$. It involves the gcd of $x$ and $n.$ That should get you the answer to the first question. For the second, I assume you mean that $G$ is cyclic of order $24$ and has a generator $a.$ This group is isomorphic to your first group and you should be able to exploit the isomorphism to answer your second question. You will need to express the generators of the order $8$ subgroup in terms of the generator $a$ of $G.$